# Spring data MongoDB get document closes to the give date and time

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I'm trying to implement the following working mongoDb query in Spring Data using MongoTemplate

db.events.aggregate([

```
    { 
        "$match" : { 
            "someId" : "5bf5372d6518b0b6315d7a29"
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$project" :{ 
            "totalValue" : 1, 
            "diff" : {
                "$abs":{ 
                    "$subtract" : [ "$dateTime" ,  new Date(2018,11,21,9,0,0)]
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$sort":{ 
            "diff":1
        }
    },
    {
        "$limit":1
    }
])
```

I have got upto this point

```
MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("someId").is("idValue"));
        ProjectionOperation projection = Aggregation.project().and("dateTime")
                .minus(format.parse(LocalDate.now().toString() + " 09:00:00").getTime()).as("diff")
                .and("totalValue").as("totalValue");
        SortOperation sort = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "diff");
        AggregationResults<Document> result = mongoTemplate
                .aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(match, projection, sort), Input.class, Document.class);
```

Following is the documents

```
db.event.insert([
{someId: "5bf5372d6518b0b6315d7a29", dateTime: new Date(2018,11,21,9,00,11), totalValue: .15},
{someId: "5bf5372d6518b0b6315d7a29", dateTime: new Date(2018,11,21,9,00,01), totalValue: .05},
{someId: "5bf5372d6518b0b6315d7a29", dateTime: new Date(2018,11,21,9,01,11), totalValue: .25},
{someId: "5bf5372d6518b0b6315d7a29", dateTime: new Date(2018,11,21,9,01,51), totalValue: .45},
{someId: "5bf5372d6518b0b6315d7a29", dateTime: new Date(2018,11,21,8,59,02), totalValue: .04},
{someId: "5bf5372d6518b0b6315d7a29", dateTime: new Date(2018,11,21,8,55,11), totalValue: .95},
{someId: "5bf5372d6518b0b6315d7a28", dateTime: new Date(2018,11,21,9,01,51), totalValue: .051},
{someId: "5bf5372d6518b0b6315d7a28", dateTime: new Date(2018,11,21,8,59,02), totalValue: .041},
{someId: "5bf5372d6518b0b6315d7a28", dateTime: new Date(2018,11,21,8,55,11), totalValue: .053},
{someId: "5bf5372d6518b0b6315d7a29", dateTime: new Date(2018,11,22,8,59,02), totalValue: .974},
{someId: "5bf5372d6518b0b6315d7a29", dateTime: new Date(2018,11,22,8,55,11), totalValue: .9},
{someId: "5bf5372d6518b0b6315d7a28", dateTime: new Date(2018,11,22,9,01,51), totalValue: .151},
{someId: "5bf5372d6518b0b6315d7a28", dateTime: new Date(2018,11,22,8,59,02), totalValue: .241}])
```

Expected output is : 0.05 (as it is close to the date time 21-11-2018 09:00:00)

Comment: That's not really wise. That calculation requires a collection scan, which means reading every document in your collection. It would be far faster ( as well as easy to implement ) to simply get the first document which is "greater than" and the first which is "less than" and then compare those two documents. In this case the cost of two requests is far less than the cost of the proposed aggregation code. Use in production at your own peril, and if this were for my application, I would reject the code commit for something like this.

Comment: I'm just a newbie to mongoDB pls excuse my aggregation method.Thank you for valuable comment, I was successfully achieve it in the way you mentioned.